# PHP - If variable's character is number then do something

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, maxlength

I created a PHP page that show names from a table, there is some names is too long, I want to make if `$name` is 12 characters then replace what after 12 characters with `...`
this is my code

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`")or die(mysql_error());
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $name= $arr['name'];
    echo '</br>';
    echo $name;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Use `strlen()` function to know the length

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$name = (strlen($arr['name']) > 12) ? substr($arr['name'],0,12) . "..." : $arr['name'];
```

This is a conditional assignment. If `$arr['name']` is greater than 12 characters, then it truncates it to 12 characters and adds "...". Otherwise, it uses the full name.

Comment: You could use the substr_replace function as well. The code would be:
`substr_replace($arr['name'],"...",12)` instead of `substr($arr['name'])."..."`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (strlen($name) > 12)
    $name = substr($name, 0, 12) . '...';
```

https://php.net/strlen

https://php.net/substr

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
if( strlen($arr['name']) > 12)
{
 substr($arr['name'],0,12)."...";
}
```

So, your code will look like:

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`")or die(mysql_error());
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
$name= $arr['name'];
echo '</br>';
if(strlen($name) > 12)
  {
  substr($name,0,12) . "...";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:-

```
<?php
$mystring = "this is a test string to check that";

if( strlen($mystring) >= 12)
{
 $result= substr($mystring,0,12);
 $result .='...';
}
    echo $result;

?>
```